# CIVICRM 5.62 - Frontend Event Calendar

Tags: calendar, civicrm-event

We are making the transition from 5.46  to 5.62 CIVICRM.  In 5.46, we are a heavy user of the event calendar.  That extension does not appear to work under 5.62.  In looking at the extensions directory, I do not see an event calendar extension.  How can I go about getting an event calendar display for 5.62?

Answer (score 1):

There are very few differences between 5.46 and 5.62 that would cause extensions to suddenly become incompatible. I think chances are very good your extension will continue working normally.